# Почему выдает два числа при выполнении кода?

Tags: python

```
n = int(input('Введите число n: ')
k = int(input('Введите число k: ') 


def my(n, k):
    if n > 20:
        return 0
    elif n <= 20: 
        total_t = 0 
   
        for i in range(1, n+1):
            if i % 2 == 0: 
                total_t += (i**k) 
                print(total_t)


my(n, k)
```

Comment: Оно может выдать и больше 2х чисел. У вас выводится число в степени k при четных i. Таких чисел по коду может быть до 10

Comment: а сколько должно выдавать и почему?

Comment: Он должен выдавать только одну строку: сумму четных чисел n в степень k

Comment: Ну так конечную сумму нужно выводить после цикла, а не внутри

Answer (score 1):

Потому что print() стоит в теле цикла for и выполняется столько раз, сколько выполняется условие if. И если вы говорите, что нужна сумма чётных чисел n в степени k, тогда возведение в степень нужно также выводить из цикла for.

```
n = int(input('Введите число n:'))
k = int(input('Введите число k: '))

 def my(n, k):
    if n > 20:
        return 0
    elif n <= 20:
        total_t = 0
        for i in range(1, n + 1):
            if i % 2 == 0:
                total_t += i
        total_t **= k
        print(total_t)

my(n, k)
```

Answer (score 0):

Если функцию определять необязательно:

```
print(0 if n > 20 else sum([i ** k for i in range(1, n+1) if i % 2 == 0]))
```

Если обязательно:

```
def my(n,k)
    return 0 if n > 20 else sum([i ** k for i in range(1, n+1) if i % 2 == 0])

print(my(n,k))
```

А почему конкретно Ваш код работает некорректно, Вам уже ответил @Oleg_S, не буду повторяться.

Answer (score -1):

Если я правильно понял автора.

```
n = int(input("Введите число n: "))
k = int(input("Введите число k: "))

def my(n, k):
    if n > 20:
        return 0
    elif n <= 20: 
        total_t = 0 
        for i in range(1, n+1):
            if i % 2 == 0: 
                total_t += (i**k) 
    return total_t
res = my(n, k)
print(res)
```